# Huge SharePoint 2007 Sites migration to 2010 version

Tags: migration

We have a SharePoint 2007 environment which has to be migrated to 2010 version. The problem is that all the content database put together will be around 3 TB. If someone here has undergone such a massive migration, please let me your best thoughts.

I'm looking for what approach you used?
Have you used any 3rd party tool?
Which 3rd party tool is most preferred?
What kind of problems you faced?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

You really do not want to migrate everything as-is, especially for such a volume. From experience, I'm willing to bet that a good chunk of that 3TB is accessed only rarely, if at all, but it still has an impact on site browsing performance. Identify your larger sites / lists as prime candidates for cleanup. What type of documents do you have? What's taking the most space?

1. Clean up your existing content (delete, re-structure, archive)
2. Design your new structure
3. Move the content

I'm going to post a link from a colleague related to this topic: [Migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 – A real life scenario - Part 3](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-migration-from-2007-to-2010-a-real-life-scenario-part-3)

Self-promoting link : Check out [Sharegate](http://en.share-gate.com) to migrate your content. It has no volume limit on content migration (*I work for the makers of Sharegate*).

If you want to migrate whole sites / structures / farms, there are plenty of tools that will do that too from AvePoint, Axeler, Idera, Metavis, Tzunami.

Also semi-self promoting (or rather promoting my field of work :D) : If you do not have strong expertise in house with SP2010 and SharePoint in general, **hire help**. Someone to help you with the move and with the differences between 2007 and 2010 will be a good investment. I have seen many customers call us *after* the move, helpless with an expensive farm used at 10% of it's features.

*Trust me*, migration is really one of those cases where preparation is half the battle. SharePoint farms are expensive to keep up. SharePoint SQL storage (particularly high-availability storage) is expensive. This is a good opportunity to do this right and maximise your ROI.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a customer on moving about 21TB of databases from 2007 to 2010. We used the detach/attach database method. This is a solid method. It also allowed us to move a site at a time, minimizing downtime for all of the sites. The time killer was of course moving the SQL backups from one server to the other, but otherwise it wasn't bad.

HTH